# MacBook Pro 2015 13" says fully charged but does not turn on

Tags: macbook-pro

I have a MacBook Pro from 2015, and I haven't used it in a while. I connected a charger until I saw it's full and tried to turn it on but nothing is happening.
Also the trackpad is not clickable.
What can I do?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try SMC reset?

Comment: Hi @Udhy, I tried it.
Also opened the case and disconnected the battery and connected again.

Comment: The MacBook should boot when the battery is reconnected and the charger plugged in, so I guess there is clearly an issue with the logic board.

Comment: Read www.reddit.com/r/mac many people having issues with black screens on Macs in the past days.